# VBA fails when opening PowerPoint presentation on Windows 7

Tags: excel, vba, windows-7, powerpoint

I wrote a VBA macro in Excel 2007 on Windows XP to copy data from an excel spreadsheet into a powerpoint presentation.
When this macro enabled spreadsheet was run on a fresh install of Windows 7 it fails.
So I pulled out the code that fails to pin point the problem and it seems to fail when trying to open an existing powerpoint file. I have tried running this code in both Office 2010 and Office 2007.

The code I am trying to use it (just the problem parts shown below)

```
Sub test()
   Dim PowerPointApplication As PowerPoint.Application
   Dim PowerPointFile As PowerPoint.Presentation

   Set PowerPointApplication = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
   Set PowerPointFile = PowerPointApplication.Presentations.Open("PATH_TO_FILE\test.pptx")
End Sub
```

The macro fails on the Presentations.Open line above with the following error

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed
```

I have already enabled the PowerPoint 12.0 Object Library in the references settings in the VBEditor for the spreadsheet. All the other references match exactly with the file that runs without error on my Windows XP box.

I have looked all over the web for an answer and cant find anything. I read something about Windows 7 and offline files, so tried turning that off but it didnt help.

I am logged in as an administrator user as well, and tried moving the pptx that I am opening to other directories as well with no success.

I am running the following version of Windows:

```
Windows 7 Professional
Service Pack 1
64 Bit
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you remove the Powerpoint reference and change `PowerPoint.Application` and `PowerPoint.Presentation` to `Object`? also add a `PowerPointApplication.Visible=True` after you `createobject`

Comment: The code is working on my end, with two minor differences: I declared a string for the file path and it's PowerPoint 14.0, not 12.0, on my end. Sid's approach also works well. Are you sure your path is declared correctly? You were moving computers so it might have changed. The `80004005` error on my end shows up when I pass an erroneous file path. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just tried what you suggested, so unlinking the Powerpoint reference and using Object type instead of the powerpoint types, and added a Visible=True (which I was using but forgot to add to the code above) and still getting the same error.

Could the problem be the PowerPoint object library version? I am only running 12?
Since writing this post I have also updated Office, as there was a service pack 2 released but that hasnt helped at all. Any other suggestions?

Comment: BK201 - I tried moving the file to the root directory (C:) so the path is C:\file.pptx and still the same error. Then I tried setting the path in a String variable instead of directly in the Open function and still the same problem. :S

FYI: Since the upgrade made this morning I now have PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library and no change, still getting the error.

Comment: Works under XP but not under Win7 ... might you be running into a UAC issue?  Make sure you have full privileges for the directory where the file's stored or as a test, put it in your Temp directory.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your comments.
I thought it was the UAC on Win7 too but I have tried the following with no success.

1. Turned the UAC for the user down to never notify
2. Turned UAC off in the registry
3. User is an administrator
4. Moved the file to open into the Temp directory
   C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp

Still get the exact same error.

Am at a complete loss here on this one! Makes no sense at all...

Comment: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?591505-RESOLVED-Run-time-error-%91-2147467259-(80004005)%92

Answer (score 0):

Is PATH_TO_FILE a variable (or constant)??

If so shouldn't it be

`PowerPointFile = PowerPointApplication.Presentations.Open(PATH_TO_FILE & "\test.pptx")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment John, although I posted this 7 years ago, from memory the PATH_TO_FILE is not a variable but just an example of me showing you that there is an absolute path in the code, without putting the actual path but thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This does work in office 2016 on Win7 SP1 64bit OS

Should be good for Office 2010.

Could be John's advise on the path to file, also.

```
Sub test()
Dim PowerPointFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPTObj As Object
Set PPTObj = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")

Set PowerPointFile = PPTObj.Presentations.Open("C:\test.pptx")

End Sub
```