# VBA - Automated PowerPoint won't open .pptx file that is being used by another User

Tags: vba, object, powerpoint

I am creating a script that copies slides from various other .pptx files into a Master PowerPoint, but if one of the files is opened by another User at the same time the macro executes I receive an 80004005 error.  My script is as follows:

```
Public Sub Update()

Dim PPTApp As Object
Dim PPT As Object
Dim MasterPPT As Presentation
Dim Total As Integer
Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim Folder As Scripting.Folder
Dim SubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim File As Scripting.File

Set MasterPPT = Presentations("Combined Staff Agenda Template.pptm")
Total = MasterPPT.Slides.Count

Set PPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

' Sets the first ComboBox destination folder
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder("O:\org\acle\Common\PE_SHARE\Technical Staff Meeting Agendas\Individual Slides\" & Order_UserForm.comboFirst.Value)

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    For Each File In SubFolder.Files

    ' Copies and pastes all slides for each file
    Set PPT = PPTApp.Presentations.Open(File.Path, ReadOnly:=msoTrue, WithWindow:=msoFalse)
    PPT.Slides.Range.Copy
    MasterPPT.Slides.Paste (Total)

    PPT.Close

    Total = MasterPPT.Slides.Count

    Next File
Next SubFolder
```

The `For Each` loop is repeated twice for two more folders, and then the sub routine ends.  The folder system is organized as follows: Parent Directory ("Technical Staff Meeting Agendas") > "Individual Slides" > Three (3) Department Folders > Individual User Folders with a .pptx file in each.  Any workaround for accessing the `File.Path` if it is already opened?

Comment: Presumably you're getting an error message on the `Presentations.Open` method, right?  What's the error number/description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely untested, but let's try something like this (assuming you're getting an error on `Presentations.Open`. I added an error-handling block around this method call, and based on the documentation ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746171%28v=office.14%29.aspx)) it looks like the `.Open` method's `Untitled` argument is equivalent to creating a copy of the file.

If that doesn't work, let me know. I can revise to explicitly create and open a copy of the file and open that, instead.

**UPDATE** Since the `Untitled` property didn't work, let's try explicitly creating a copy of the file. I did not include any "cleanup" code to remove the copied versions.

```
Public Sub Update()

Dim PPTApp As Object
Dim PPT As Object
Dim MasterPPT As Presentation
Dim Total As Integer
Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim Folder As Scripting.Folder
Dim SubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim File As Scripting.File

Set MasterPPT = Presentations("Combined Staff Agenda Template.pptm")
Total = MasterPPT.Slides.Count

Set PPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

' Sets the first ComboBox destination folder
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder("O:\org\acle\Common\PE_SHARE\Technical Staff Meeting Agendas\Individual Slides\" & Order_UserForm.comboFirst.Value)

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    For Each File In SubFolder.Files

    ' Copies and pastes all slides for each file
    On Error GoTo FileInUseError
    Set PPT = PPTApp.Presentations.Open(File.Path, ReadOnly:=msoTrue, WithWindow:=msoFalse)
    On Error GoTo 0
    PPT.Slides.Range.Copy
    MasterPPT.Slides.Paste (Total)

    PPT.Close

    Total = MasterPPT.Slides.Count

    Next File
Next SubFolder

'## It's important to put this before your error-handling block:
Exit Sub

'## Error handling:
Err.Clear

'## First attempt, did not work as expected
'Set PPT = PPTApp.Presentations.Open(File.Path, ReadOnly:=msoTrue, Untitled:=msoTrue, WithWindow:=msoFalse)

 '## Second attempt. You will need to add some logic to remove these files or do it manually.
Dim copyPath as String
copyPath = Replace(File.Path, File.Name, "Copy of " & File.Name)
FSO.CopyFile File.Path, copyPath, True
Set PPT = PPTApp.Presentations.Open(copyPath)


Resume Next

End Sub
```

**Update 2**

Other things you could try (not likely to work, but you should try them anyways):

I notice that this code is executing from within PowerPoint, so one thing that doesn't make sense is the:  `Set PPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")`.  You're already running an instance of PPT, and only one instance of PPT runs (unlike Excel which can have multiple instances).  So get rid of that line entirely.

```
'Set PPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
```

Then also you can get rid of the variable `PPTApp`.  I notice you use a combination of early- and late-binding for your PowerPoint Object Variables.  That doesn't really make sense and while I wouldn't expect that to cause any errors, you never know.

```
'Dim PPTApp as Object 'PowerPoint.Application  '## This is unnecessary!!
Dim PPT as Presentation
Dim MasterPPT as Presentation
```

If all else fails, open the new file `WithWindow=msoTrue` and step through the code line by line using F8...

**UPDATE 3**

While I am not able to test a file that is locked/in-use by *another* user, I was able to test what happens if I have a file that is in use by *myself*.  I use the following code and identify that the `Files` iteration will eventually encounter the lock/tmp version of the file, beginning with "~" tilde character.  These are ordinarily hidden files, but FSO is picking them up in the iteration anyways.

Aside from that, I encounter similar errors if the file is not a valid PPT filetype (PPT, PPTX, PPTM, XML, etc.).  I used the following code which prints a log of errors in the Immediate window (and informs you with MsgBox prompt) if there are errors.

```
Sub Test()
Dim MasterPPT As Presentation
Dim PPT As Presentation
Dim Total As Integer
Dim FSO As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim File As Object
Dim errMsg$
Dim copyPath$

Set MasterPPT = ActivePresentation '## Modify as needed.

Total = MasterPPT.Slides.Count

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Sets the first ComboBox destination folder // MODIFY AS NEEDED
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\david_zemens\Desktop\CHARTING STANDARDS")

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    For Each File In SubFolder.Files
        ' Copies and pastes all slides for each file
        On Error GoTo FileInUseError:
        ' Make sure it's a PPT file:
        If File.Type Like "Microsoft PowerPoint*" Then
10:
            Set PPT = Presentations.Open(File.Path, ReadOnly:=msoTrue, WithWindow:=msoFalse)
20:
           PPT.Slides.Range.Copy
30:
            MasterPPT.Slides.Paste (Total)

            PPT.Close

        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    Total = MasterPPT.Slides.Count
NextFile:
    Next File
Next SubFolder

'## It's important to put this before your error-handling block:
Set FSO = Nothing
Set Folder = Nothing
Set SubFolder = Nothing
Set File = Nothing

Exit Sub

FileInUseError:
'## Error handling:
'## Display information about the error
errMsg = "Error No.: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf
errMsg = errMsg & "Description: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf
errMsg = errMsg & "At line #: " & Erl & vbCrLf
errMsg = errMsg & "File.Name: " & File.Name
Debug.Print errMsg & vbCrLf
MsgBox errMsg, vbInformation, "Error!"
Err.Clear
Resume NextFile

End Sub
```

Comment: David, I did try the `Untitled` method previously, but it didn't seem to work. I will try your script to see if it changes anything! Do you know what the `FileInUseError` references? Also, the error I'm receiving at the `Presentations.Open` is: "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'; PowerPoint could not open the file."  What is strange is that the script still copies and pastes the slide from the source presentation, but then stops with this error.

Comment: Hmmmm that sounds odd. OK well if this still doesn't work let's see if the revision above would help.

Comment: David, I am receiving an Expected Function/Variable error for `.CopyFile`, even though it recognizes the function when I enter it.  Any suggestions?  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: hmm let's try another revision. See above.

Comment: Same error :/. Do you think changing the `Dim` of my variables might help (using different association for the files)?

Comment: No, let's try one more thing... revised.

Comment: Once again, the slide of the opened PowerPoint copied over, but then I received the same Run-time error, this time with "Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed.  The Debug indicates the `Set PPT = PPTApp.Presentations.Open(copyPath)` line.

Comment: It does not seem possible that it could copy slides from a presentation it is unable to open.  That error typically would indicate that the specified file is not found. What happens when you try to open such file manually?

Comment: David, if I try to open a .pptx file that is opened by another user I receive a warning indicating that it is open by another user.  The dialogue asks if I'd like to open a read-only copy, and then my only options are `Open` or `Cancel`.  If I open the file, there is a status bar that suggests I `Save As`.  It doesn't seem like I can make changes to the PowerPoint however, which might be the issue (I can still copy the slides in the file, I just can't paste them in the same PowerPoint or change them).

Comment: Make your `PPApp.Visible = True`, open the file `WithWindow=msoTrue` and step through the code using F8.  I don't have any means of testing/to open a file in use by another user, since I don't have any other users...

It sounds like, despite the error message, your procedure **is** somehow copying the slides as desired. If so, although I hate to recommend it, `On Error Resume Next` would be a temporary fix.

Comment: I made a few other suggestions, not sure if they will make any difference, but you should try them.

Comment: David, thank you again for your help.  Unfortunately I am still receiving the same Runtime-error code, this time with "Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed".  I wasn't aware that you can't have multiple instances of PowerPoint (I write VB for Excel mostly), so thank you for that correction!  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282386/vba-fails-when-opening-powerpoint-presentation-on-windows-7) is the only other reference that I've seen online regarding the same problem, but it doesn't seem like a solution was reached.

Comment: Everything I've seen about that error says one of two things: **1**: An invalid file path (seems unlikely, since you're using a `File.Path` rather than a computed string), or **2**: Missing reference to PPT (which cannot be the problem, since you are working in PPT you don't need the reference).  This really does not make sense at all.  It's hard to believe that it's actually copying the slides if this error is raised, but MS sometimes raises *wrong* error messages. I am curious, if you make the `WithWindow=msoTrue` and break/debug on the error, is the presentation actually open in PowerPoint?

Comment: David, with the current error ("Method 'Open' of object..."), the slides of the .pptx opened by another user doesn't copy anymore (I don't know what changed).  There is one file that opens successfully before I reach the erroneous .pptx, and with `WithWindow:=msoTrue` I can see a window open and then close immediately (doesn't actually display anything due to lack of time).  I know it's not a file path issue, because if none of the PowerPoint files are open by another user it works successfully.

Comment: OK. I'm going to assume erroneous PPTX was not *ever* being copied it's possible you were just mistaken on that. It can't copy what is not open. That is the only thing that makes sense.  There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code. It *should* work. Perhaps there are some properties of the file that are problematic? Have you tested this on **OTHER** files in-use by someone else? Or just this one?  The error-handling block should not fail on the **Copy** version of the file, so I think that tells me there is a porblem with the file itself, not the script/code.

Comment: And by the way, I generally refrain from asking for votes, although I have not "solved" the problem,but a courteous upvote on this answer would be nice, given the amount of debugging I'm doing to help you.

Comment: David, I do appreciate your help with this.  The slide was being copied at one point (I was receiving the same error number with a different caption), but it is no longer doing that.  I have not tried with any of the other files, although all of them should be of the same format.  I will try to change some of the file properties if possible.  I think the error is just due to the fact that PowerPoint doesn't know how to handle two .pptx files being accessed at the same time.

Comment: PPT can certainly open and interact with two PPTX files at the same time, I don't think that is the problem.  I still think there must be something funky about the particular file that causes the error.

Comment: Are all files in the folder/subfolder valid PPT/PPTX/PPTM files?  I have tested this code with a file in use by my own machine, and it successfully opens a [Read Only] version of the same file, `WithWindow=msoFalse`.  One thing you will run in to is the possibility of attempting to open the lock file, a temporary file begining with a tilde character `~`.  That will raise this error for sure.

Comment: I think you might be onto something!  I changed my settings to display hidden files, and there are multiple copies of the error presentation (i.e. "Copy of Copy of Copy of Copy of..." and so on).  I will try to write in a string that excludes any files with a ~$

Comment: I wouldn't bother with that. Those are technically valid filenames (although unlikely to be true filenames).  I made another revision above that simply logs the errors so that you can review them, to see if anything is a problem.

Comment: David, I figured it out.  It was the temporary files that the script was trying to pull.  I created a short `If` statement to skip anything with a "~$", but now it faulted due to a "TemporaryRibbonCache.xml" file in a particular folder.  I think I'm going to try to add a statement that only allows it to retrieve .pptx files to help eliminate these issues (because multiple users will have access to the files).  Thank you again for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @CJK try my new answer (subroutine called `Test()`).  That already has logic to use only PPT files, and the error-handling will trap the temporary lock files, too.

Comment: I probably should have asked what is the value of `File.Path` when that error is raised in the first place, but it didn't seem possible that could be the problem.  That also explains why the slides may appear to have been copied -- they *were* copied, and then the code failed on the temp file :)

Comment: David, thank you very much!  Your script works as intended, and I'm relieved to know that we found the issue!  In my situation, I have three of the same copy loops for three different directories, so I'll probably have to find a workaround the `NextFile:` because there will be three instances of that.  Also, may I ask what the `10:`, `20:`, and `30:` are for?

Comment: Assigning line numbers like `10:`, etc., allows you to reference the intrinsic `Erl` object.  I rarely use it, but it sometimes comes in handy for error-trapping. If you look in the error log or MsgBox notifiction, it will tell you either 10, 20 or 30 on failure, and that would indicate the next statement is exactly where the code failed. They are not really necessary.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use three loops for three directories :)  Unless you're really doing three totally different operations inside the loop, you can modify this function to work on multiple directories.